# Why is ‘prejudice’ syllabified as Prej-u-dice?

Tags: pronunciation, syllables

While reading a book, I noticed *prejudice* was hyphenated to the next line in the following form: *prej-udice.* As I found it quite strange, I searched online for its syllables and apparently it had its syllables as *prej-u-dice,* so the book was not wrong about the hyphenation. But still, my heart strongly suggested that *pre-ju-dice* would be a more intuitive way to syllable the word.

Notice that the following words are partly similar but syllabled differently:

- *Conjugation(con-ju-ga-tion)*
- *Perjury(per-ju-ry)*

I wonder what makes *prejudice* so different from those words that it has *j* separated from *u* in the syllables?

As suggested in the comments, I'm adding the reference to the hyphenation in question:

- The exact location is the 6th line from the bottom of page 176 of Justice (ISBN 978-0-374-53250-5);
- [image: Reference image] 
  <sub>The original link to Google Books seemed to only work in my country, so I'm posting the search result image instead.</sub>

Comment: In your heart do your pronounce it starting with “pree-“ or “predge”? I say “predge” ...

Comment: I say prĕ rather than prē but I'd never hyphenate it as *prej-udice.* Imagine having "prej-" at the end of a line and "udice" on the next. Really difficult to make sense of. It would be really helpful to say **where** you found this and how many other resources you checked.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, I see. I always thought the syllables matter when it comes to hyphenation. Anyways, the line is from the 6th line from the bottom of page 176 of Justice.

https://books.google.com/books?id=SKEeHVwT5UMC&lpg=PA176&pg=PA176#v=onepage&q=involves%20no%20such%20prejudice&f=false

Comment: Please add complete reference information **to the question,** rather than bury it in comments.

Comment: Of course, the actual text isn't available at your link. I'd guess it's just extremely poor printing (where a possible exception to a rule hasn't been taken into account).

Comment: @AndrewLeach Strange. It worked for me while I haven't purchased the book or anything. I posted the image instead. I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: LaTeX uses prej-u-dice; Apparently Knuth's hyphenation algorithm is fully documented in [his books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computers_and_Typesetting) (I thought the font suggested LaTeX, but the "j" isn't from Computer Modern)

Comment: @ChrisH The font in the illustration is Eric Gill's *Perpetua.*

Comment: @Andrew thanks.  once I zoomed in it obviously wasn't CM but by then I'd looked up the hyphenation pattern

Comment: As a side note, _prej-_ at the end of a line gives you a much better clue to what follows than _pre-_. As somebody who voices internally when reading, this is a definite bonus -- I don't have to backtrack and change my internal pronunciation from /priː/ to /prɛ/.

Comment: who says splitting needs to follow syllable boundaries? https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/385/what-are-the-rules-for-splitting-words-at-the-end-of-a-line has a variety of rules of thumb in its answers more complicated than "splitting must be done on syllable boundaries"

Comment: The words you compare with are not really similar, because there are two consonants between the first two syllables. So the first consontant is naturally in the first syllable, and the second consontant is in the second syllable.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Prejudice* is syllabified as /ˈprɛd͡ʒ.ə.dəs/ and not */ˈprɛ.d͡ʒə.dəs/ because the lax vowel /ɛ/ doesn't occur at the end of syllables in English and therefore it should have a coda—a consonant after it (see [Maximal Onset Principle](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/558949/365490)).

Also according to [John Wells' syllabification](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/565269/365490), ‘consonants are syllabified with the more strongly stressed of two flanking syllables’. The first syllable in *prejudice* has primary stress on it, so the /d͡ʒ/ is syllabified with that syllable, giving /ˈprɛd͡ʒ.ə.dəs/.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prejudice) and [American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=prejudice) give:

> prej·​u·​dice
> prej·u·diced, prej·u·dic·ing, prej·u·dic·es

So yes, it should be hyphenated *prej·​u·​dice*.

Comment: Should it be hyphenated that way as well? I would say etymology holds the trump card there.

Comment: @AndrewLeach If you let etymology hold the trump card w.r.t. hyphenation, then you get hyphenations like helico-/pter, photo-/graphy and thermo-/meter.

Comment: @RosieF I did say **there,** and it may be an exception which proves the rule; although your last two hyphenations don't seem bad to me.

Comment: "/ɛ/ doesn't occur at the end of syllables in English". "Meh" begs to differ :)

Comment: But you can't hyphenate "Meh" so that is irrelevant :)

Comment: @chepner: Yeah ... I've mentioned that in the linked answer (“Maximal Onset Principle”). :P

Comment: @chepner And besides, it's spelled with a silent h, so the point is moot

Comment: @NoName Well, yes. If the h weren't silent, it would conform to the "can't end in /ɛ/" rule.

Comment: " because the lax vowel /ɛ/ doesn't occur at the end of syllables" That's a bit circular. Also, the second vowel of "prejudice" is \u\, although it can be reduced to \ə\, and neither vowel works well at the beginning of a syllable. Putting \u\ at the beginning of a syllable almost always induces a yod. "Also according to John Wells' syllabification, ‘consonants are syllabified with the more strongly stressed of two flanking syllables" How it's pronounced is more important than what some guy says the syllabification should be. And M-W gives both syllabifications.

Comment: @Acccumulation schwa appears in onset all the time. "a" is almost always just a schwa with no onset for instance

Answer (score 0):

The first syllable is *prej* because the e is a short vowel and needs the *j* to close the syllable. If is did not have the j, the e would say long e.